# Django model unique=True not throwing any error which used in atomic transaction

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-3.0

Scenario:
I am trying to create/insert data to Django model (POSTGRES database) employee and profile.
When I insert duplicate records (i.e. with duplicate work_email and duplicate employee_id) I am expecting a database error in an atomic transaction.

However, the below code doesn't throw any error, but when I see the database table no duplicate is created.

Dropped a database and created a new DB and new migrations to make sure there is no problem with the sync. However, the result is the same with no errors.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    """
    Employee table containing all the employee information.
    """
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    employee_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=False,
        unique=True,
        primary_key=True,
        error_messages={'employee_id': "A user with employee id already exists."}
    )

class Profile(AbstractUser):
    """
    Enhancing user model with additional fields. This is in relation with a table ProfileExtras.
    Extras can be utilised to add any fields to further enhance Profile with key value pair.
    """
    email = None
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=False)
    work_email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=50,
        blank=False,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
        error_messages={'work_email': "A user with work email already exists."}
    )


def create_employee(app_context, data_dict):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            employee_model = models.Employee()
            profile_model = models.Profile()
            # Data insertion logic
            # e.g. setattr(employee_model, "first_name", "xxxxxx")
            employee_model.profile = profile_model
            profile_model.save()
            employee_model.save()

    except Exception as e:
        log.error(e)
        raise e
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I was testing with Django test. It is found that data is not retained between each test, hence the duplicate error is not raised.